# Can SharePoint 2013 be Installed across multiple domains for a three-tier farm without configuring domain trust?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-farm, farm-setup

Can SharePoint 2013 be Installed across multiple domains for a three-tier farm without configuring domain trust?

> Ex:
>
> Domain A : Application servers and database servers.
>
> Domain B : Front end servers.

Domain trust should not be configured and front end servers should use SQL authentication to join the farm and SQL aliases are configured in front end servers.

Would greatly appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with 2013+. What is the purpose behind doing so? If you're doing this because you want to place the FEs in a DMZ, re-think the strategy. It would be far more secure to place the entire farm internally and use a reverse proxy in the DMZ (or a service like Azure AD App Proxy).

EDIT: And with your FEs in another untrusted domain, you wouldn't be able to use the People Picker for users in DomainA regardless.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. FEs supposed to have external facing web sites and should be in DMZ and SQL server should be in domain A based on the existing policy. If the application servers are moved to DMZ then can the farm be installed using SQL authentication? ADFS can be configured for the people picker to resolve users from domain A.

Comment: Honestly, this is one of those 'revisit your policy' as it is outmoded. And SAML will not resolve users; it will accept any value you input as there is nothing to resolve against. SAML also does not work with Cloud Search Service, should you go down that path.